# Pandas MulitIndex forces Datetime.date objects to Timestamp objects

Tags: datetime, pandas, timestamp

I recently updated Pandas and found this strange behaviour which broke some of my existing code. 
I was using a column of Datetime.date objects as a the second level in a two-level MulitIndex. 
However, when setting the index with the latest version, the Datetime.date objects are converted to Timestamp objects with 00:00:00 as the time component:

```css
>>> pd.__version__
'0.15.1'
>>> df
          0  ID        date
0  0.486567  10  2014-11-12
1  0.214374  20  2014-11-13
>>> df.date[0]
datetime.date(2014, 11, 12)
>>> df.set_index(['ID', 'date']).index[0]
(10, Timestamp('2014-11-12 00:00:00'))
```

This doesn't happen with version 0.14 or older, nor does it happen for a single columns of dates set to index, only for MulitIndices.

There is a hack to get around it, setting the dates to a single level index, adding the other level and then swapping:

```css
>>> df.set_index('date').set_index('ID', append=True).index.swaplevel(0, 1)[0]
(10, datetime.date(2014, 11, 12))
```

This seems strange and I wondered was it intentional and whether there is a proper way to use datetime.date objects in the new version.

Answer (score 1):

see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7888)

Their was an inconsistency in how date-likes (datetime.date,datetime.datetime,Timestamp) were inferred in a MultiIndex level. This led to the creation of an object dtyped Index rather than a DatetimeIndex. datetime.date are second class objects in pandas as they are not efficiently represented.

If you really really want to create this, you can do this:

```
In [8]: pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([Index([datetime.date(2013,1,1)]),['a']])
Out[8]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[2013-01-01], [u'a']],
           labels=[[0], [0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

We came across the same issue and it is still a problem in 0.16.  We consider it a bug as it is inconsistent with the operation of creating a single index, and only occurs with multiindex.  Why silently change the type if we choose to have it as datetime.date?  Set_index should just set the index without changing things.

We don't need the time component.  If we wanted to speed things up and do it more efficiently by using a timestamp we should be able to choose that.

It breaks all the code where the index is converted back and forth between columns and index when the table is manipulated (pivoting etc, as it does silent type conversion).  Also breaks interaction with other applications and code we have no control over.